# Body of old post is essentially: "Here is my problem statement with some broken links"

Tags: discussion, specific-question, old-questions, broken-link

I began editing [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18762164/webfont-is-jumping-in-internet-explorer-8-10) and inevitably the post became just a line or two as a problem statement, with two broken web links.

My first thought was to flag the post as non-reproducible (based on post merit).

Though the answer seems helpful enough, I couldn't come up with a way to reframe the question in a way that provided enough meat to make the whole post useful. 
I believe flagging as a duplicate (if found) could be solution.

What is the proper course of action here?

Comment: Thanks for the tag edit @vaultah

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Close it.  The question doesn't have the information contained in it to answer it, so I wouldn't bother looking for a duplicate that could fit it.

If the OP elects to come back to edit it and fill in more details and code, then they can, but closing it is the *best* option here.

Comment: Meta effect took care of it, thanks for the advice. I'll keep it in mind for the future.

Comment: s/*best*/*only*/

Comment: @Braiam:  Touche.